# trying to search through 2 arrays at once C# and print out any matching info

Tags: c#

I have a search method that is trying to match a director name to an entry in one and/or two arrays. However, I cannot figure out how to print the names of multiple titles if the director has more than one movie in either array.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
if (director == myDVDs[i].Director || director == myBlu[i].Director)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i + 1, myBlu[i].Title);

    EndOptions();

}
else if (director != myDVDs[i].Director && director != myBlu[i].Director)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} does not have a movie in the database try again",     director);
    Console.Clear();
    Search();
}
```

Comment: Are `myDVDs` and `myBlu` related somehow? Or they are just to lists that contain movies? To put it other way `myDVDs[0].Title == myBlu[0].Title` - true or false?

Comment: its kinda both. the way its supposed to be setup is that a DVD only has a DVD but a bluray has a bluray entity and a DVD entity so that when you add a bluray your also adding a DVD

Comment: I Figured it out thanks anyway everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `Concat`, like this:

```
var matching = myDVDs.Concat(myBlu).Where(d => d.Director == director);
int count = 1;
foreach (var m in matching) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", count++, m.Title);
}
```

Comment: Yes, same for me, maybe `Join()`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My understanding of the question is that he's got his DVDs and Blurays in separate arrays, and he's looking for all titles made by a particular director. He's not joining them on a director, just searching two separate collections of identically typed items.

Comment: @abatishchev I think he's searching two collections that are independent of each other, and should not be joined. It happens that they all contain movies, but other than that there's no relation on which to join.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight They don't think that your answer is wrong, but the Concatenate() method doesn't exist, maybe do you mean Concat().

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Absolutely, you are right. I guess I rely on autocompletion in Visual Studio too much, so I don't remember the names of lots of methods (`Substr` vs `Substring`, `Concat` vs `Concatenate`, and so on).

Comment: +1. Concat is the simplest solution if types of elements in array are the same.

Comment: I think you also need to .Select(x => x.Title).Distinct()

Answer (score 2):

Generic solution which simplyfies adding a new movie type. To find titles used LINQ [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx), [Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx), yo might need adding `using System.Linq` to use these methods:

```
var dvds = new List<IMovie>
           {
              new DvdMovie {Title = "DVD1", Director = "Director1"},
              new DvdMovie {Title = "DVD2", Director = "Director1"},
              new DvdMovie {Title = "DVD3", Director = "Director2"}
           };

var bluerays = new List<IMovie>
           {
               new BlueRayMovie {Title = "BR1", Director = "Director3"},
               new BlueRayMovie {Title = "BR2", Director = "Director3"},
               new BlueRayMovie {Title = "BR3", Director = "Director1"}
           };

var allMovies = new List<IEnumerable<IMovie>> {dvds, bluerays};
string searchFor = "Director1";

// Main query, all other initialization code and types are below
IEnumerable<string> titles = allMovies.SelectMany(l => 
    l.Where(sl => sl.Director == searchFor)
    .Select(m => m.Title));

if (titles != null && titles.Count() > 0)
{
    // OUTPUTs: DVD1, DVD2, BR3
    foreach (var title in titles)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(title);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nothing found for " + searchFor);
}
```

## Types

```
public interface IMovie
{
    string Director { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
}

// TODO: Make immutable. 
// Make setter private and introduce parametrized constructor    
public class DvdMovie : IMovie
{
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

// TODO: Make immutable. 
// Make setter private and introduce parametrized constructor                
public class BlueRayMovie : IMovie
{
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```